# Find side length of triangle given one angle, one side and a relation

Tags: trigonometry

Triangle has side $a$ length 10 cm, angle $C$ 120°.

side b $= c-14$

How can I use this to work out the side length of $b$?

I tried using the sine rule, doing

$(sin 120)/(c)=(sin A)(10)$

so $8.66=c sin A$

But I'm stuck here and I don't think I've done this correctly?

The answer appears to be 42, if it helps.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @paf I tried the sine rule, which I couldn't proceed further with because there were two unknowns.

Comment: Could you edit your question and show us exactly your attempt, please?

Comment: @paf I did. Would you be able to help please?

Answer (score 2):

Note that from the law of sines you have all three equations
$$\frac{\sin 120 ^\circ}{c}=\frac{\sin A}{10}=\frac{\sin B}{c-14}$$

Furthermore, you have that the angles $$A+B=60^\circ$$

This gives you enough equations. Remember to "convert" to radians before evaluating the sines.

EDIT: Actually, **using the law of cosines is much easier**, since (using $c=b+14$) you have $$(b+14)^2=10^2+b^2-2\times 10b\cos 120^\circ$$

However, from this one obtains $b<0$, which seems strange to say the least - the conclusion is therefore either that 1) the problem is flawed, 2) your reproduction of the problem is flawed, because the triangle cannot be constructed.